# Codepoint mismatch between Java and C

Tags: java, c, kotlin, codepoint, imgui

So, I'm having some problems with the following char `–` in a port of imgui to [kotlin](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui)

After digging the whole day into Charsets and encodings, I came down to my only hope: rely on the unicode codepoints.

That char on the jvm

`"–"[0].toInt() // same as codePointAt()`

returns codepoint [u2013](https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/)

On C, I'm not sure, but since this is what is being [done](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_draw.cpp#L2538-L2546):

```
const ImFontGlyph* ImFont::FindGlyph(ImWchar c) const
{
    if (c >= IndexLookup.Size)
        return FallbackGlyph;
    const ImWchar i = IndexLookup.Data[c];
    if (i == (ImWchar)-1)
        return FallbackGlyph;
    return &Glyphs.Data[i];
}
```

Where

`typedef unsigned short ImWchar`

and

`ImVector<ImWchar> IndexLookup; // Sparse. Index glyphs by Unicode code-point.`

So, doing this

```
char* a = "–";
int b = a[0];
```

returns codepoint [u0096](https://unicode-table.com/en/0096/)

As far as I read, it look like over `127`(`0x7F`) we are in the "Extended Ascii" territory, which is bad, because it appears there are different versions/interpretation of it.

For example, this [encoding table](http://www.asciitable.com/) doesn't match my codepoint, but the [Cp1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) does, so I'm inclined to think that this is what is actually being used on C.

In the table at the bottom of the link just mentioned, you can actually see that `150` (decimal, count from the right column with the given number) corresponds indeed to `2013` (hex, I find it a little incoherent, but anyway).

To solve this, I tried to convert my `String`s on Kotlin to the same encoding (ignoring for the moment that this is of course platform-specific), so for every `c: Char`

`"$c".toByteArray(Charset.forName("Cp1252"))[0].toUnsignedInt`

This works, but breaks rendering for foreign fonts, such as chinese, japanese, etc..

So, my question is: why the difference between `u2013` on JVM and `u0096` on C?

Which is the right way to deal with this?

Comment: Try `L"–"` in C, which creates UTF-16 strings on Windows. (You can also just do L'–' without having to create a string then read a character from it.)

Comment: I can't see the point to that, anyway, with `char* a = L"–";`I get the following `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [2]' to 'char *'`

Comment: It should work with `ImWchar*`, which is what you want isn't it? Maybe that would need a cast, but it would be the correct data.

Comment: It wanted the cast indeed. And it's actually `8211` in this case

Comment: 8211 is 0x2013 in decimal.

Comment: yeah, but what is going then without `L`?

Comment: Like you said, it’s a CP1252 string. You can convert that to wide chars using [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar).

Comment: "Extended Ascii": There are only two interpretations of it. 1) One very specific character encoding (in which case there is no reason to call it "Extended Ascii", just say which is it). 2) Adaptive to the user's system's current settings followed up by optional locale changes within the program (which is rarely but sometimes exactly what you want).

Comment: In practice, I think ‘extended ASCII’ usually refers to Windows Latin-1 AKA CP1252.  (That's mostly the same as ISO Latin-1 AKA ISO 8859-1 (which matches the first 256 Unicode chars) except that it has things like curly quotes and long dashes in chars 128–159 where ISO Latin-1 has control characters.)

Comment: **Which C++** and with what options? Your claimed 'C' is actually C++, although you can have the same issue in C. The Java standard defines it to use UTF-16, plus there is one dominant implementation (Sun-now-Oracle), but the C++ and C standards make (source and execution) character encodings implementation-dependent and there are many thousands of C and C++ implementations which make many different choices in this area; some compilers support multiple options.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, sorry but I have no idea about which options exactly you refer (I just cloned it and opened in VS). Anyway, I kind of found a solution for the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I solved like [this](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/imgui/internal/helpers.kt#L418-L457) on Windows, I inserted this function before retrieving the char codepoint.
It basically remaps all those chars which differs from ISO-8859-1. You can see them in this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set), they are all those with that light grey border.

```
internal fun Char.remapCodepointIfProblematic(): Int {
    val i = toInt()
    return when (Platform.get()) {
        /*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set
         *  manually remap the difference from  ISO-8859-1 */
        Platform.WINDOWS -> when (i) {
            // 8_128
            0x20AC -> 128 // €
            0x201A -> 130 // ‚
            0x0192 -> 131 // ƒ
            0x201E -> 132 // „
            0x2026 -> 133 // …
            0x2020 -> 134 // †
            0x2021 -> 135 // ‡
            0x02C6 -> 136 // ˆ
            0x2030 -> 137 // ‰
            0x0160 -> 138 // Š
            0x2039 -> 139 // ‹
            0x0152 -> 140 // Œ
            0x017D -> 142 // Ž
            // 9_144
            0x2018 -> 145 // ‘
            0x2019 -> 146 // ’
            0x201C -> 147 // “
            0x201D -> 148 // ”
            0x2022 -> 149 // •
            0x2013 -> 150 // –
            0x2014 -> 151 // —
            0x02DC -> 152 // ˜
            0x2122 -> 153 // ™
            0x0161 -> 154 // š
            0x203A -> 155 // ›
            0x0153 -> 156 // œ
            0x017E -> 158 // ž
            0x0178 -> 159 // Ÿ
            else -> i
        }
        else -> i // TODO
    }
}
```